# Return a Matching Element from a List in a Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of integers (gtin) and a pandas data frame (df) with one column containing a list in each row (df['gtins'])

I would like to define a new column in the data frame (df['gtin_match']) that returns the first matching element in the data frame list to the standalone list.

I have tried using the code below with the apply function and a lambda function, but it returns a list of the list in df['gtins'].

How can I fix this?

```
gtin = [1234, 456, 2005, 91]

df['gtin_match'] = df['gtins'].apply(lambda x: [x for i in range(0, len(x)) if int(x[i]) in gtin])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your comprehension, you should return `x[i]` since `x` itself is the list object and you just want to return the int:

```
df['gtin_match'] = df['gtins'].apply(lambda x: [x[i] for i in range(0, len(x)) if int(x[i]) in gtin])
```